# Qual o significado de "Oscultador", de onde vem?

Tags: significado, origem

[No StackOverflow em Português comumente é utilizado o termo "oscultador"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=oscultador) para referenciar-se ao "ouvinte" de eventos (oscultador parece muito melhor :P), em inglês é chamado de *listener*.

Eu pesquisei, mas não encontrei nenhuma referencia dessa palavra fora da área de programação. Então gostaria de saber se ela é um termo técnico da programação, ou se em Português Europeu ela possui um significado específico, pois no Brasil nunca vi ele sendo usado, a não ser no StackOverflow em Português.

Obs.: Encontrei o termo "auscultador" que tem os significados de "escutar" como pessoa que está escutando, peça no interior de aparelho telefônico para "escutar" ou aparelho médico que auxilia na escuta (estetoscópio).

Comment: Nem no SOpt eu vi isso...

Comment: Clica no [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=oscultador) Jorge. :) Geralmente é o @Sergio que usa.

Comment: Carlos o Sérgio é Português, estranho que eu nunca tinha visto esse termo.

Comment: Na verdade é só o Sérgio que usa.

Comment: Acho que eu já usei uma vez (influenciado por ele :P)

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/163/regarding-an-edit-suggestion

Comment: Haha :) Pergunta excelente. A ver se é desta que descobrimos qual a palavra correta :)

Comment: Será que "observador de evento" neste caso seria mais correta? acho que vou ter algum trabalho a mudar as minhas respostas todas se a minha versão fôr incorreta mesmo :P

Comment: @Sergio boa sorte que está mesmo incorreta, olha eu gosto de auscultador, acho que só te enganaste mesmo foi a escrever.

Comment: Hahhaha que confusão @Sergio :P ... Acho que "observador de evento" fica bom..

Comment: Listener em inglês é ouvinte em português. Nenhuma dúvida.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo o dicionário da priberam [oscultador](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/oscultador) não existe.

Existe sim auscultador que é aquele que ausculta (ouve).

#### aus·cul·ta·dor |ô|

> (latim auscultator, -oris, o que ouve, ouvinte) adjectivo e
> substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Que ou aquele que ausculta. substantivo masculino
> 2. Instrumento com que se ausculta.
> 3. Estetoscópio.
> 4. Peça do telefone que se aproxima do ouvido.Ver imagem
> 5. Dispositivo, usado nas orelhas, que converte um sinal eléctrico em som. (Mais usado no plural.)Ver imagem = FONE
> 6. Cada um dos terminais desse dispositivo, colocado em cada orelha.Ver imagem = FONE
>
> "auscultador", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/auscultador [consultado em
> 06-08-2015].

Comment: O auscultador também poderia ser é um mêdico.....